# Reduce/Remove Sparks in AC and DC Contacts of Relays

Tags: relay, power-electronics, electrical, spark

I see that there are sparks being generated whenever there is a connection established between two contact points in the relays. So is there a way to reduce/remove those spark generated in the relays.

Comment: There can be but it might upset the operation of the load (of which is unspecified).

Comment: Need to be more specific, DC or AC, what is the load. Some relays are filled with a special gas to reduce the arcing (sparks).

Comment: I am using Mechanical DPST relays. Some will be controlling AC loads and some relays DC loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, the most generic is an R-C quench circuit.

[image]

You can even get them in one package.  People often use 0.1 uF and 100 ohms, but you may want to use trial and error to get the best results for your application.
If the load is at line voltage you might use an X2 for the capacitor for safety.  One capacitor company used to loan (sell?) R-C selection boxes to make this convenient.  There are also formulas published.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Snubbers as above are useful.  One less appreciated source of contact damage is excessively long release times caused by the common "diode across the coil" protection.

A series diode and zener across the coil, or at lower cost, a zener across the transistor can significantly speed up relay opening time and reduce arcing especially with inductive loads and DC sources.

(see https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/resistive-load  section 5.1 schematic B)

Answer (score 1):

Not to sound midevil but... there is another way! For one most relays that take a big amp rating normally have grease inside that helps with arcing. This is a good start to try. Starter car relay for example.  If you ever seen like a 80v dc lawnmower for example they solved the problem with 2 relays.  You use a small low voltage 2 throw relay. One side will energize your larger relay and the other side will bridge the larger relays gap with a inline resistor, like a 1k ceramic type. This first connect will not power your motor but will pre-complete the circuit so the spark is not present when you engage the bigger relay that does the main work.  I know low tech not over complex is never the answer people want on forums, but this method has been used for years.